# How to query for entities with many-to-many relationships?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 entities that are in relationship. The following is a simplified example of my classes:

```
@Entity
public class Action {}

@Entity
public class Instance {

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Action> actions;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<CadSystem> cadSystems;

}

@Entity
public class CadSystem {}
```

How can I query for all `Instance`s that belong to a specific `Action` and `CadSystem`?
For example I would like to do the following in a `JpaRepository`:

```
public interface InstanceRepository extends JpaRepository<Instance, Long> {

    List<Instance> findByActionAndCadSystem(Action action, CadSystem cadSystem);

}
```

But this is not possible because `Instance` has no fields named `action` and `cadSystem`.
I think the following would work:

```
public interface InstanceRepository extends JpaRepository<Instance, Long> {

    List<Instance> findByActionsAndCadSystems(Set<Action> actions, Set<CadSystem> cadSystems);

}
```

But in this case I would always have to create a new `Set` with only one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a query. Also, note that since the associations are many-to-many, this query might return several actions:

```
select i from Instance i
join i.actions action
join i.cadSystems cadSystem
where action = :action
and cadSystem = :cadSystem
```